# How to emulate swipe actions with keyboard for Android-x86?

Tags: android-emulator, android-x86, game-controllers

I want to play some RPG games on Android, but I own a mediocre phone which does not run them well. Running them inside Android-x86 on my PC sure runs them better, but there's just one problem: these apps don't support keyboard/mouse control. They have virtual navigation buttons on screen, which need be both tapped and swiped. I can do that with the mouse, but that's not useful. I need to bind specific tap and swipe actions with keyboard buttons, so that whenever I press that key, the corresponding tap/swipe actions will be emulated on corresponding part of the screen. Is there a solution for this? Or is it a far cry?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. Managed to do this with this specific emulator.
Check it out. https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-use-keyboard-mapping-to-play-android-games-on-pc/

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but nòt with any emulator, with Lineage, directly as an OS on the PC.